# Show a record and change next in the same form (next/previous record)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel-5, crud

I would like to know how I can show a record with the next button on the same form.

I attach an example below

[image]

On the left side I have the data of a client (this part is fixed) and on the right side I have the data of the pets from client. Client can have several pets, but I would like to be able to see them one by one, and I can see the next pet, in the same form with the next button in the registry

I use a laravel 5 framework. Exist any way to make this (ajax?) or another better option?

I would like know example that makes this

Txh everybody

Comment: Please share your code, otherwise we cannot judge how to do better

Comment: I think the simple solution is to make a carousel in HTML / CSS / JS.

Comment: I still do not have any code for this part. Because I do not know how to raise the problem :(